# How can I access the posts of my own fb page using graph api version 2.0

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

It want to access the posts of the FB page owned by me using the graph api version 2.0 .
I know how to do it, I have the code but the issue I am facing is that I need to submit my app for review as `manage_accounts` permission is granted only after the app **facebook**
Can I do this without getting the app reviewed as I need it by tomorrow?

I get the following error in the graph api explorer for this query:

**QUERY:**  `me?fields=id,name,accounts{access_token}`

**Error**

> The field 'accounts' is only accessible on the User object after the user grants the 'manage_pages' permission.

Please let me know if there is a way around this?

Thank YOU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is `manage_pages`, not `manage_accounts`. You can use `manage_pages` for everyone with a role in the App (Admin, Developer, Tester). If you want to make your App available for all users, you have to go through the review process with `manage_pages`.

Either way, you have to authorize the user with `manage_pages`, that´s exactly what the error message tells you.